# Why Can't My Xcode Project Folder Be Found in Terminal?

Tags: xcode, terminal, cocoapods

I am trying to use CocoaPods with my Xcode project -- Study Hall -- but when I try to locate the project on my desktop I get an error.

I have done the following,

```
$ ls

$ cd Desktop

$ ls

$ cd Study Hall
```

I expected for the Xcode project to come up on the Terminal but instead it gives me the error:

> -bash: cd: Study: No such file or directory.

Why is this happening and how can I get it to function properly? This is actually my first time installing CocoaPods and using the Terminal so it is really confusing for me.

Comment: Spaces in Terminal are special.  Try putting your folder name in quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ cd Study\ Hall
```

You probably forgot to escape the space in the middle. Otherwise the terminal does not know if this should be treated as two parameters (Study + Hall) divided with a space or one parameter ("Study Hall") where the space is part of the name

Comment: Nitpick: it's not Terminal that cares about the space, but rather whatever shell the OP is using.